# How to achieve this layout with div and css?

Tags: css, layout, html

I want to design a static webpage with a very easy and strict layout.
I want to achieve this with div and css.

Here is an idea how it should look:

```
image HEADING                          -> .... Content continues here 
      teasertext tesertext             Content Content Content Content 
                                       Content Content Content Content 
      Content starts here ... Content  Content Content Content Content 
      Content Content Content Content  Content Content Content Content 
      Content Content Content .....->  Content Content Content Content 

      -----------------    -----------------
      |Large Image 1  |    | Large Image 2 |          Imagedescription
      |               |    |               |          Imagedescription
      |               |    |               |          Imagedescription
      -----------------    -----------------
      image copyright
```

The basic idea is to have a small image at the left (a red square).
The rest of the page is aligned right to the image.
First the heading followed by a teaser text.

The content area should be a fixed size and the text should overflow to the right area (if larger)

After that I have two images with a description to the right and a copyright below.

I have never done anything before with css / div and the biggest problem for me is how to define the content area as an overflow.
I have been messing around with this for some time and can't figure out how to do this.

I hope this is an easy task for a experienced web developer, who can give me a hint.

This is what i have so far:

css:

```
*.left_area {
    padding:10px;
    text-align:left;
    width:40px; 
    float:left; 
} 

*.right_area {
    padding:10px;
    text-align:left;
    width:90%; 
    float:left; 
} 

*.heading {
    font-family:Tahoma,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

*.teaser {
    font-family:Tahoma,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

*.content {
    width:50%;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
}
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="left_area">
    <img src="square.png"  width="16" height="16" />
</div>
<div class="right_area">

    <div class="heading">
    Heading Heading Heading
    </div>

    <div class="teaser">
    Teaser Teaser Teaser Teaser Teaser Teaser
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content 
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you stick up an example of what you've got already?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float2 Not exactly you need but a small idea.

Comment: “The content area should be a fixed size and the text should overflow to the right area (if larger)” — Could you explain a bit further what this means? When you say a fixed size, do you mean a fixed width, and fixed height, or both?

Comment: The text width should be 50%, the height will be a fixed pixel size that I will decide later. Basically the text should continue on the right (at the same position as the heading) if it does not fit into the space.

Comment: @freebird never recommend w3schools.com, please read here why http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: @limelights, freebird isn't recommending the website itself, he's just using their tryit editor to show an example. I don't think that is a bad practice.

Comment: @Rorok_89 Why not use a jsfiddle or tinker.io instead? :) I might be overly sensitive but I'm thinking that clicking a link to "learn more" is very easy. If my comment was regarded as hostile then, freebird, sorry for that it wasn't my intention to be rude or percieved as a meanie! :)

Comment: @limelights I know that you provided the link for me to understand what the link tries to , I appreciate that.However I was just trying to suggest him a simple idea.No issues.Thanks.

Comment: @limelights no, I didn't see it as hostile either. I was just pointing up my opinion, but always in friendly manner. Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/columns - I believe this is what you need to format the `div.content` element (or in general - the upper half of your page).

I am not sure whether the html you provided is really the one which you have drawn in that nice ascii-picture. But the large images seem to be simple to format. Just wrap all of them in some element (`div` maybe) with `overflow:hidden` - to give it a BFC *(you may read about it at http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/ )* , and add `float: left` or just leave them inline.

In general, I would suggest similar structure of HTML:

```
<div id="textSection">
  <h1>HEADING</h1>
  <p>Teasertext...</p>
  <p>Content...</p>
</div>
<div id="imagesSection">
  <div class="image">
    <img src=".." alt="..">
    <p>Image copyright or something</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="descriptions">
    <p>Imagedescription...</p>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Apply `columns` to `#textSection`. Apply `overflow:hidden` to `#imageSection`. Apply `float:left` to `#imageSection > *` or (alternatively) if you want images and image descriptions to behave like table cells, just make them as such:

```css
#textSection {
     -moz-columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
          columns: 2;
}
#imagesSection {
  display: table;/* add width, margins and so on */
}
#imagesSection > * {
  display: table-cell;/* add widths, paddings, and so on */
}
```

I must admit that I have not tested that code, but I hope I did no grave mistake :)

Comment: Ah, if you are able to use HTML 5, then I suggest `<figure>` instead of `<div class="image">` and `<section>` instead of `<div>`s. But that is another story.

Comment: Seems good, but not supported by some older browsers. My final solution now includes two content sections (I devide the text myself into two blocks, one on the left, on on the right)